How to use Or (||) in a less verbose test function?
Suppose I have myStrList, a list of one-character strings:
myStrList = {"A", "a", "B", "b"};

I wish to create a function that will return True if a string is either "A" or "a", and False otherwise. I wish to Map this function across the list myStrList.

Method (1). One way to do this is to use MemberQ to test if a string is a member (element) of the list {"A", "a"}. This method gives the expected output:

(* Method (1): using MemberQ *)
Map[MemberQ[{"A", "a"}, #] &, myStrList]
(* {True, True, False, False} *)


Method (2). Another way is to use MatchQ with a pattern object involving Alternatives (or, equivalently, |). This method also gives the expected output:

(* Method (2): using MatchQ and Alternatives (|) *)
Map[MatchQ[#, Alternatives["A", "a"]] &, myStrList]
Map[MatchQ[#, "A" | "a"] &, myStrList]
(* {True, True, False, False} *)
(* {True, True, False, False} *)


Method (3). Still another way is to use Or (or, equivalently, ||), the logical OR. Again, this method gives the expected output:

(* Method (3): using Or (||) *)
Map[Or[# == "A", # == "a"] &, myStrList]
Map[# == "A" || # == "a" &, myStrList]
(* {True, True, False, False} *)
(* {True, True, False, False} *)

Is there a way to condense method (3), so that it is less verbose? Instead of asking whether # == "A" OR # == "a", can I ask whether # == "A" OR "a"? I tried the following:
Map[# == Or["A", "a"] &, myStrList]
Map[# == ("A" || "a") &, myStrList]
(* {"A" == ("A" || "a"), "a" == ("A" || "a"),
  "B" == ("A" || "a"), "b" == ("A" || "a")} *)
(* {"A" == ("A" || "a"), "a" == ("A" || "a"),
  "B" == ("A" || "a"), "b" == ("A" || "a")} *)

Neither of the above gives the expected output. It looks as though the equality test is being held. I notice that Or (or, equivalently, ||) has attribute HoldAll:
Attributes[Or]
(* {Flat, HoldAll, OneIdentity, Protected} *)

Could it be that I need to use Evaluate to force the evaluation of # == ("A" || "a")? It doesn't seem that Evaluate helps in this regard:
Map[Evaluate[# == Or["A", "a"]] &, myStrList]
Map[Evaluate[# == ("A" || "a")] &, myStrList]
Map[# == Evaluate[Or["A", "a"]] &, myStrList]
Map[# == Evaluate[("A" || "a")] &, myStrList]
(* {"A" == ("A" || "a"), "a" == ("A" || "a"),
  "B" == ("A" || "a"), "b" == ("A" || "a")} *)
(* {"A" == ("A" || "a"), "a" == ("A" || "a"),
  "B" == ("A" || "a"), "b" == ("A" || "a")} *)
(* {"A" == ("A" || "a"), "a" == ("A" || "a"),
  "B" == ("A" || "a"), "b" == ("A" || "a")} *)
(* {"A" == ("A" || "a"), "a" == ("A" || "a"),
  "B" == ("A" || "a"), "b" == ("A" || "a")} *)

Nor does it seem that using Simplify or FullSimplify will evaluate the expressions:
Simplify /@ {"A" == ("A" || "a"), "a" == ("A" || "a"),
  "B" == ("A" || "a"), "b" == ("A" || "a")}
FullSimplify /@ {"A" == ("A" || "a"), "a" == ("A" || "a"),
  "B" == ("A" || "a"), "b" == ("A" || "a")}
(* {"A" == ("A" || "a"), "a" == ("A" || "a"),
  "B" == ("A" || "a"), "b" == ("A" || "a")} *)
(* {"A" == ("A" || "a"), "a" == ("A" || "a"),
  "B" == ("A" || "a"), "b" == ("A" || "a")} *)

The solution to this may be obvious, but it's not obvious to me. How can I force testing expressions like "A" == ("A" || "a") to evaluate? Or where am I going wrong conceptually?

# == Or["A", "a"] & does not look right to me. The syntax of Or is not like this. But why not just use something like AnyTrue[myStrList,Or[#=="A",#=="a"]&]. I know you said you wanted to use Map. In Mathematica there are many ways to do the same thing. I see nothing wrong with your earlier tries also. But the last one, your Or usage is not correct. You can fix it by doing Or[# == "A", # == "a"] i.e. move the # inside.

If you specifically want Or in your test, then no, I don't think there's a way to condense your test. Or expects to be applied to boolean expressions. The expression Or["A", "a"] is applying Or to strings. The semantic that you're looking for in something like Or["A", "a"] is already provided by Alternatives, which you've already used successfully in another version of your test.

If by "condense" you mean something more like "reduce duplicated constructs", then you could do a variety of things. E.g. test = (Apply[Or]@*Comap[MatchQ /@ {"A", "a"}]). To demonstrate, test["A"] gives True and test["b"] gives False.

StringMatchQ["A" | "a"]@myStrList ?

Or, ToUpperCase[#] == "A" & /@ myStrList

@Nasser's suggestion of AnyTrue[] will "create a function that will return True..." as you say you want. Further, it will return True as soon as it runs into an "a" or an "A", whereas Map[] will pointlessly continue to check all remaining strings.

Or[] is not way represent alternative values. It's a logical connective to connect boolean expressions (whose value is presumed to be from the set {True, False}). Since a string does not represent a boolean expression, Mathematica does not know what to do with it and leaves it alone. About the only evaluation one can get is ("a" || "A") == ("A" || "a") since each side is identical. Now Or could connect to equalities, as  in Thread[# == ("A" || "a"), Or] & /@ myStrList.

Perhaps I misread?: If you wish a list of True/False, then what's wrong with Map[MatchQ["A" | "a"]]@myStrList? I suppose your question is really just about what Or[] means and how it works in Mathematica. Have you looked at the documentation, because its evaluation to only True or False is clearly stated at the top; hence, it cannot be equal to a string.

StringMatchQ works with regular expressions or Mathematica string expressions.
myStrList = {"A", "a", "B", "b"};
(* this regular expression matches any of the characters in square brackets *)
StringMatchQ[myStrList, RegularExpression["[Aa]"]]
(* (?i) is an option to match while ignoring case *)
StringMatchQ[myStrList, RegularExpression["(?i)A"]]
(* the IgnoreCase option works the same way *)
StringMatchQ[myStrList, RegularExpression["A"], IgnoreCase->True]
(* use string expression to match a list of characters *)
StringMatchQ[myStrList, "A"|"a"]
StringMatchQ[myStrList, Alternatives@@{"A", "a"}]
(* ... and IgnoreCase *)
StringMatchQ[myStrList, "A", IgnoreCase -> True]

The result is the same for each example.

{True, True, False, False}


The same match expressions work with StringCases and StringReplace so it's a flexible method for other problems.
StringCases[myStrList, RegularExpression["[Aa]"]]


{{"A"}, {"a"}, {""}, {""}}


StringReplace[myStrList, RegularExpression["[Aa]"] -> "X"]


{{"X"}, {"X"}, {"B"}, {"b"}}



Conceptually, the best way to quickly determine if an element is in a set is by using a HashSet:
set = CreateDataStructure["HashSet", {"A", "a"}]
set["MemberQ", #] & /@ {"A", "a", "B", "b"}


You can define a listable function and use it without Map:
f["a" | "A"] = True;
f[_] = False;
Attributes[f] = {Listable};

myStrList = {"A", "a", "B", "b"};
f[myStrList]
(*    {True, True, False, False}    *)

Or you could use a Dispatch:
d = Dispatch[{("A" | "a") -> True, _String -> False}];

myStrList /. d
(*    {True, True, False, False}    *)


myStrList = {"A", "a", "B", "b"};
Or @@ Thread[# == {"A", "a"}] & /@ myStrList


{True, True, False, False}


Thread[# == Or["A", "a"], Or] & /@ myStrList also works.

@SjoerdSmit Yes, but my code is by a tiny bit shorter :-)

Not true, it's actually the same number of characters. And my code can be 2 chars shorter as well: Thread[# == "A" || "a", Or] &

@SjoerdSmit Mine StringLength["Or@@Thread[#=={\"A\",\"a\"}]&/@myStrList"] == 36 Yours StringLength["Thread[#==Or[\"A\",\"a\"],Or]&/@myStrList"] == 37. The code in your last comment does not work :-)

Here is a way to live dangerously by using $Pre:
$Pre = Function[# /. (x_ == HoldPattern[Or[s__String]]) :> 
  (Or @@ (EqualTo[x] /@ {s}))];

Map[# == ("A" || "a") &, myStrList]
(* {True, True, False, False} *)

